# ELASTICSEARCH - Filter values in inner hits

Tags: elasticsearch

In this query I want to get the fields witg values "data.addresses.ces.cp": "true"" from the most recent doc, and then but it returns true values, like false
How could I filter only true?

```
{ "_source": "created_at",
  "size": 1, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "created_at.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data.addresses",
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": ["data.addresses.ces.secondname", "data.addresses.ces.cp"],
        "size":100
      },
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "data.addresses.ces",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "data.addresses.ces.cp": "true"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
                "ces" : [
                  {
                    "secondname" : "lopez",
                    "cp" : true
                  },
                  {
                    "secondname" : "gomez",
                    "cp" : false          <--------------- error
                  },
                  {
                    "secondname" : "garcia",
                    "cp" : false         <---------------error
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `inner_hits` section to the innermost nested query?

Comment: I have moved the inner_hits to the innermost nested and It worked
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `inner_hits` inside the innermost nested query:

```
{ "_source": "created_at",
  "size": 1, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "created_at.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data.addresses",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "data.addresses.ces",
          "inner_hits": {
            "_source": ["data.addresses.ces.secondname", "data.addresses.ces.cp"],
            "size":100
          },
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "data.addresses.ces.cp": "true"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: How could I make a aggregation to the field "data.addresses.ces.cp"?

Comment: @MiguelBarrios can you create a new question since this one is closed?

Comment: Thank you Val, here is a new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600024/elasticserch-inner-hits-aggregations

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat confusing why you'd query `data.addresses.services.cp` but you wanna retrieve `data.addresses.ces.cp`. What's this `ces`? Is it a typo from servi**ces**?

In any case, as @Val suggested, you can place another `inner_hits` into the innermost nested query:

```json
{
  "_source": [
    "created_at"
  ],
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "inner_hits": {
        "size": 100,
        "name": "ih_addresses"
      },
      "path": "data.addresses",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "inner_hits": {
            "name": "ih_services"
          },
          "path": "data.addresses.services",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "data.addresses.services.cp": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `inner_hits` can have a `name` attribute to distinguish one from the other.